# Вода и воск, Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать симуляцию процесса литья воска в воду в Unity? 
1)Воск до встречи с водой - жидкость. 
2)Воск после встречи с водой - твёрдое тело, но не сразу, а с задержкой. 
Как подобное можно реализовать? Как вообще на воду поставить коллайдер?

Comment: Боюсь это просто в одном ответе не объяснить. Мне кажется проще найти ассет с управлением физикой текучих элементов и с ними играться..... что-то типа из этого https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=Liquid&price:0     ну или из платных.